# Where is Everybody?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, hard-sci-fi, paradox

Someone wrote a short story about the Fermi paradox—well, probably more than one person—but I have a specific story in mind.

I can only recall the broad outline.

A group of human explorers find a planet perfect for settlement, but before they can claim it, an alien walks up to them and sits down to tell them a little story.

This is the first alien that any human has ever met and the explorers almost shoot him in fear. But he calms them somehow and explains that humans live in an area of space that has been emptied by war. Everything has been wiped out, except apparently for us.

Here be spoilers:

> Why? Because the biggest, baddest aliens of all time used to live there and the rest of the galaxy got together and killed the evil ones off. Didn't humans ever wonder why they had never met any aliens before?

And

> All the dangerous aliens had been wiped out except for one planet—Earth.

One more

> Then he killed everyone with a thought.

The story was probably written in the late 1940s through the 1950s. It's too straightforward for a 1960s story. I might have read it in an old magazine or in an anthology. I can't be sure.

But I'd sure like to know its name and who wrote it.

Comment: @MikeScott - Shoot, looks like you're right. And answered twice.

Comment: [Answered four times.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aanswer%20shaara%20%22all%20the%20way%20back%22)